# Capturar el valor de un Input Text que se encuentra dentro de una Fila de una Tabla, al presionar un Checkbox con jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image: Captura de la imagen]

Tengo esta tabla, como se ve en la **captura**, donde se agregan los datos dinamicamente del buscador con `jQuery`.

Necesito **obtener** el valor del `Input` **Cantidad**, cuando se active el `Checkbox` del **Descuento**.

En cada fila `td` tengo `Inputs` y una columna `tr` con el **ID** del producto, por el momento solo he logrado capturar el ID y el Estado del `CheckBox`:

```
    $(document).on("click",".activate_descuento",function(){
          var valores = "";
          $(this).parents("tr").find("td").each(function() {
            valores += $(this).html() + "\n";
          });
          console.log(valores);
          alert(valores);
    });
```

NOTA: Si hay muchos productos que pueda agregar, la Cantidad como otros `Inputs` tienen el mismo `ID` y `NAME` por lo tanto se comportará como vector.

Comment: Puedes agregar el HTML o el PHP que estas usando para armar tu tabla? Creo que le estas dando mucha vuelta a algo tan sencillo, pero habrá que analizar tu código.

Comment: @AlejandroHurtado es necesario que compartas un poco sobre la estructura HTML con la que armas la tabla.

Comment: Un extracto le genero cada TR con sus respectivos TD y dentro Inputs, algo asi:
  ` rhtml =
                       '<tr><td>
      .......
                       <td> <input type="text" name="cantidad" class="form-control tcantidad" style="width: 100px;"></td>
      .....
                       </tr>';
y asi agrego con Jquery
 $('#'+id_tabla).append(rhtml); `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Planteare una respuesta en base a mi percepción de la imagen, pues a mi parecer estas usando campos de texto dentro de las celdas, a continuación te propongo una idea sencilla «Observa el resultado en la consola del ejemplo»

```js
$(".descuento").on("click",function() {
  var fila = $(this).parents("tr");
  var nombre = fila.find(".nombre").val();
  var cantidad = fila.find(".cantidad").val();
  var precio = fila.find(".precio").val();
  var stock = fila.find(".stock").text();
  
  // Suponiendo que así determinas el descuento
  var descuento = 0;
  if (fila.find(".descuento").prop("checked")) {
      descuento = 0.15;
  }
  
  console.log(`El producto ${nombre} cuesta ${cantidad*precio*(1-descuento)}`);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" class="nombre" disabled value="AMBIANTE X 1LT"></td>
        <td><input type="number" class="cantidad" value="32"></td>
        <td><input type="number" step="any" class="precio" disabled value="18.00"></td>
        <td><span class="stock">38</span></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="descuento" checked></td>
        <td><button class="quitar">Quitar</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" class="nombre" disabled value="CHANTPAK X 1 LT"></td>
        <td><input type="number" class="cantidad"></td>
        <td><input type="number" step="any" class="precio" disabled value="21.00"></td>
        <td><span class="stock">200</span></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="descuento"></td>
        <td><button class="quitar">Quitar</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Te darás cuenta que aprovechamos las `clases` para individualizar cada uno de los datos de cada celda, sin embargo si me pidieses una sugerencia seria usar los atributos `data-*` y dejes las clases para aplicar estilos.

Espero que les sea de mucha utilidad.

Comment: Es exactamente lo que quería, muchas gracias Neder

Answer (score 1):

Cree una demo para ayudarte con una mejor referencia: (también disponible en [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o8d9kqq8/12/))

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('change', '.checkbox', function() {
    if (this.checked) {
      console.log($(this).parents('tr').find('td.cantidad').html());
    }
  });
});
```

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<table style="width:100%;">
  <tr>
    <th>Nombre</th>
    <th>Cantidad</th> 
    <th>Stock</th>
    <th>Descuento</th>
    <th>Acción</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>example-name-1</td>
    <td class="cantidad">32</td> 
    <td>18</td>
    <td>38</td>
    <td><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>example-name-2</td>
    <td class="cantidad">39</td> 
    <td>135</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Cree una `table` en la cual al `td` en donde está la cantidad le agregué una clase "cantidad", el cual usarás luego para poder acceder al valor del mismo.

Comment: Primeramente gracias por tu ilustración @ecastellano, todo genial, solo tengo un pequeño detalle, dentro de TD de CLASS Cantidad tengo un Input, asi :

<td class="act_cantidad"> <input type="text" name="cantidad" class="form-control tcantidad" required  style="width: 100px;"></td>

Como puedo acceder hasta su valor del CANTIDAD?, gracias una vez mas.

Comment: En ese caso deberías utilizar console.log($(this).parents('tr').find('td.cantidad > .cantidad').html());

Con el símbolo > podrás acceder a los elementos hijos de tu td, el cual sería tu input de cantidad

Comment: @ecastellano aunque si bien puede acceder a los elementos usando descendencia en el selector una vez obtienes un elemento tipo input, la manera de capturar su valor es usando .val() en vez de .html()

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda.